# How to directly get value of text field in a given section of type structure?

Tags: templating, craft2

I am trying to get a value of a text field that is in a Section which is a *structure* and has multiple entry types. I don't want to use a loop. I tried this and some other variations but does not give me the correct value.

```
{% set value = craft.entries.section('mySectionHandle').type('entryTypeHandle').myTextFieldHandle.first() %}
```

What is the correct syntax? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
{% set value = craft.entries.section('mySectionHandle').type('entryTypeHandle').first().myTextFieldHandle %}

{{ value }}
```

Just with your field handle at the end